# Printing multiple figures in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, printdialog

Assume I produce several figures in my program. I want to give the user the option of printing them all at once. I do not want to show the **print dialog** for every page. Therefore, I am displaying it only once and for the first figure only. This is the solution that I have come up with so far:

```
figHandles = get(0, 'Children');
for currFig = 1:length(figHandles)
    if(currFig == 1)
        printdlg(figHandles(currFig)); % Shows the print dialog for the first figure
    else
        print(figHandles(currFig)); % Does not show the print dialog and uses the latest printer selection
    end
end
```

But the problem is, if the user **cancels the print** for the first figure, there is no way that I can catch it and cancel the other prints. How should I achieve that?

Comment: Based on the sources of one of the old Matlabs - not sure that it can return anything, because it uses `eval` for printing.

Comment: Quite an interesting question, but may be you should modify the title to also show that you want to retrieve the status of a print job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this one is a pretty dirty trick and there is definitely no guaranty it will work for all versions. It does work for me on Matlab 2013a / win 7.

To get Matlab to return a value as to whether it executed a print job or not, you need to insert a small hack into the `print.m` function.

---

### Hacking `print.m`

- Locate the `print.m` function. It should be in your matlab installation folders around `..\toolbox\matlab\graphics\print.m`.
- Once located, **make a backup copy!** (*this trick is minor and shouldn't break anything but we never know*).
- open the file `print.m` and locate the line `LocalPrint(pj);`, it should be near or at the end of the main function (~line 240 for me).
- Replace the line by:

.

```
pj = LocalPrint(pj); %// Add output to the call to LocalPrint
if (nargout == 1)
    varargout{1} = pj ; %// transfer this output to the output of the `print` function
end
```

- Save the file.

Done for the hack. Now every time you are calling the `print` function, you can have a return argument full of information.

---

### Applied to your case:

First, notice that on windows machines, the `printdlg` function is equivalent to call the `print` function with the `'-v'` argument.
So `printdlg(figHandle)` is exactly the same as `print('-v',figHandle)`. *(the `'-v'` stands for `verbose`)*. We are going to use that.

The output of the `print` function is going to be a structure (let's call it `pj`) with many fields. The field you want to check to know if the print command was actually executed is `pj.Return`.

```
pj.return == 0 => job cancelled
pj.return == 1 => job sent to printer
```

So in your case, after the tweak on the `print.m`, it could look like this:

```
pj = print('-v',figHandles(1)); %// Shows the print dialog for the first figure
if pj.Return %//if the first figure was actually printed (and not cancelled)
    for currFig = 2:length(figHandles)
        print(figHandles(currFig)); %// Does not show the print dialog and uses the latest printer selection
    end
end
```

---

Note: The `pj` structure contains many more reusable informations, including the print job options, the current selected printers etc ...